# Does .tar files have checksum that covers the bulk data contents?

Tags: tar, archiving

I have experienced that a .tar file was corrupted, without receiving an error when unpacking the file, so that makes me wonder:

Does .tar files have checksum that covers the bulk data contents?

Answer (score 1):

Tried a simple test making a 1 K text file of only "x", and then created a .tar file based on this.  Then modified a single "x" in the .tar file to an "y", and then unpacking.  No errors were generated at the unpacking, and a single "x" was changed to an "y", so conclusion is:

The .tar file format does not have any checksum that covers bulk data.